# XML DOM parsing returns only the first node

Tags: xml, kotlin, parsing, dom

I'm trying to perform parsing on meteo data (https://www.arpa.veneto.it/bollettini/meteo60gg/0083.xml). I would like to extract VM, VMIN and VMAX for each sensor but unfortunately, with the following code, only the first node ("Temperatura a 2m") is extracted: do you have any idea why is it happening?

```
val xmlDoc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(data)
        xmlDoc.documentElement.normalize()

        val SENSOR= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SENSOR")

        for(i in 0..SENSOR.length - 1){
            var SensorNode : Node = SENSOR.item(i)

            if (SensorNode.getNodeType() === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                var SensorElem = SensorNode as Element
                var TIPOsensorescelto = 
                val SENSORchosen = SensorElem.getElementsByTagName("PARAMNM").item(0).textContent
            val istantList = SensorElem.getElementsByTagName("DATI")

            for(i in 0..istantList.length - 1) {
                var istantNode: Node = istantList.item(i)
                if (istantNode.getNodeType() === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    val elem = istantNode as Element
                    val mMap = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
                    for(j in 0..elem.attributes.length - 1)
                    {
                        mMap.putIfAbsent(elem.attributes.item(j).nodeName, elem.attributes.item(j).nodeValue)
                    }
                    
                    /// saving stuff
                 }
              }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Probably problem is in istantList.length, because when i replace it with a number it works: any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Edited with some implementation but the problem was not solved: could it be related to "SensorElem.getElementsByTagName("DATI")"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: the problem was in the saving stuff, as I was trying to save a tag existing only for the first node. The reported code is working for me.